# Probability of sorting at least one correctly

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I have 5 balls label 1 through 5, to put one in each of 5 boxes also labeled 1 through 5. What is the probability of putting at least one ball in it's matching box?

My first approach was to calculate the chance of putting every ball in the incorrect box. Therefore the probability of getting the first ball wrong is $\frac{4}{5}$, for the second ball $\frac{3}{4}$ and so on. That gives a probability of $\frac{1}{5}$ of getting every ball wrong.

Of course this approach is wrong because the probability of picking the next ball incorrectly also depends on which balls I've already placed. So what would be the correct approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the other side. What if no ball goes into its matching box? Apply the derangements formula to get $44$. Total permuatations are $120$. Subtract $44$ from it to get $76$. Now probability will be- $\frac{76}{120}=\frac{19}{30}$

Comment: Thanks, looked into derangements and got a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the fraction of permutations of $5$ items that are [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  It is very close to $\frac 1e$ and a derivation is given in the Wikipedia page.